# Numerical computation of Heston model Integral: Simpsone Rule or Gauss-Legendre Method

Tags: option-pricing, numerical-methods, heston

I want to price a call option using the Heston model for a given set of parameters.

theory from URL: http://elis.sigmath.es.osaka-u.ac.jp/research/Heston-original.pdf

The integral equation (18) needs to be approximated.

I'd like to either use the Simpson Rule or Gauss-Legendre method for it.

Does anybody have the matlab or scilab codes for it ?

Comment: Hi Matthias, welcome to Quant.SE! I don't have the MATLAB help here but I think I remember that MATLAB has such procedures built in? Are these not sufficient or am I mistaken?

Answer (score 0):

I guess this it, but you need to create an account:

**Gauss- Kegendre method** 
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4540-legendre-gauss-quadrature-weights-and-nodes

**Simpsone Rule**
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28726-simpson-s-rule-integration/content/simpsons.m

Comment: thanks, but I was thinking of a code that is already made for this particular Heston model. I have tired to execute these functions for the Heston integral, but it did not work. The integral is quite complicated. Maybe someone has had the same problem.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry if this is late, but this is the bible of Heston (and it has code) https://www.amazon.co.uk/Heston-Model-Extensions-Matlab-Finance-ebook/dp/B00EMADBN2/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1468410988&sr=8-1&keywords=Heston+matlab

Comment: You should post the relevant mathematics from the book, rather than a link to a book